# C++ - Calculate number of slices in a pizza

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I wrote this program to calculate the number of slices for this size of pizza (diameter) given. But the results seem a bit off...  Any assistance would be much appreciated :)

For example:
If I input 18 inch pizza, it results in 4.00344 slices...
If I input 22 inch pizza, it results in 4.8931 slices...

See code below:

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    // Title of CMD Window
    system("title How many Slices are in your Pizza?");
    // Declare variables    
    double  diameter = 0.0,     // Diameter of the pizza
            slices = 0.0,       // No. of slices in the pizza
            area = 0.0,         // Area of the whole pizza
            oneSlice = 14.125;  // Area of one pizza slice
    const double PI = 3.14159;
    // Display prompt   
    cout << "What is the diameter of the pizza (inches):" << "\n";
    cin >> diameter;
    //  Calculate the area of the pizza
    area = PI * diameter;
    // Calculate number of slices for the size of pizza given
    slices = area / oneSlice;
    // Display results
    cout << "\n\n" << "You have " << slices << " slice(s) in this pizza:" <<  "\n\n"
         << "************************************" << "\n"
         << "\tDiameter of pizza= " << diameter << "\n"
         << "\tArea of pizza= " << area << "\n"
         << "************************************" << "\n";
    system("pause"); 
    return 0;
} 
// End of program
```

Comment: What would you expect the results to be and why?

Comment: area = PI * diameter; that really doesn't seem right

Comment: `area = PI * diameter; // or try area = PI * radius * radius;` -- did you try the comment's formula instead?

Comment: Everyone knows there's *always* 8 slices in a pizza.  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The area of a circle is not `pi * diameter`: That's the circumference.

You need `area = PI * (diameter / 2.0) * (diameter / 2.0);`

Comment: I think it's *such* a bad sign when the person asking the question responds to a good answer with "looks like that worked" or similar. It's like all you wanted was a quick fix, you still don't understand *why* your approach is incorrect and neither do you really care.